# Getting relocation error: I am Unable to run dotnet app using terminal on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-22.04, snap

I am using dotnet sdk snap 3.1, getting following error running app from terminal.

```
my-pc:~/git$ dotnet run --project test/src/test.api 
/home/mir/git/test/build/test.api/test.api: relocation error: 
/home/mir/git/test/build/test.api/test.api: symbol __pthread_key_create version 
GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Please advise.

Comment: You might need to reinstall dotnet on  ubuntu from scratch

Comment: already did....

Comment: that seems snap issue. need to resolve with snap